# How do I correctly export thread_local variables with g++ 4.8.1, ld 2.23.52?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

Consider the following files.

#### libfoo.h

```
class A {
    public:
        A(): foo(0){}
    private:
        int foo;    
};

//extern thread_local A a;
extern  A a;
```

#### libfoo.cc

```
#include "libfoo.h"

//thread_local A a;
A a;
```

#### main.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libfoo.h"

int main(){
    printf("%p\n", &a);
}
```

Makefile

```
CPP := g++
libPerfGraph.so: Cycles.o  PerfGraph.o Util.o
    $(CPP) $(CFLAG) -g -std=c++11 -shared  -o $@ $+ -lpthread

%.o : %.cc %.h
    $(CPP) $(CFLAG) -g -std=c++11 -fPIC -shared -o $@ -c $<
```

In the scenario above, everything works correctly. The compiler does not complain, and there is no run-time error.

However, if I uncomment the `thread_local` declarations and comment out the non-`thread_local` declarations, then I get the following nasty error when trying to compile the app.

```
g++ -o main -std=c++11 main.cc -L. -lFoo
/tmp/ccWmJGng.o: In function `TLS wrapper function for a':
main.cc:(.text._ZTW1a[_ZTW1a]+0x5): undefined reference to `TLS init function for a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

**How can I work around this error, and successfully export the thread_local library variable?**

Comment: Could export a function that returns a reference to the `thread_local` variable?

Comment: @Yakk, I did consider this workaround, but it seems like a tremendous hack. I was wondering if there was some compiler flag or macro that could be set to explicitly tell the compiler to export.

Comment: which compiler version do you use and have you tried the (non-standard) __thread keyword?

Comment: This problem also occurs with gcc (C). I think it must be a bug as the GNU gcc manual says it is permissible to have both `extern` and `_Thread_local` (or its equivalent). I am using gcc 6.3.0.